# Nginx permission denied upstream error, even after 777

Tags: nginx, permissions

I have been getting this error

> 2013/03/13 13:25:07 [crit] 49299#0: *38 rename()
>   "/var/tmp/nginx/fastcgi_temp/6/00/0000000006" to
>   "/var/cache/nginx/microcache/8/fd/c36e398490d9b70e3c98ba094d065fd8"
>   failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream

I tried other informations in Nginx and SO forums like changing the owner of folder/file, deleting the microcache folder for Nginx to create new by itself, but nothing seems to work.

My Nginx config has `www` as user(owner, in FreeBSD) all these folders `/var/tmp/nginx/fastcgi_temp/` and `/var/cache/nginx/microcache/` has `www` as user(owner) and `wheel` as group.

To test it I even gave `-R 777` to those above mentioned folders and restart nginx, but `error.log` still says same error. Can't even think of what might possibly be wrong here, any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Great idea to willy-nilly set permissions across the board to 0777. Better install that machine from  scratch now, it is probably mesed up beyond repair.

Comment: I know 0777 is not right thing, but 0777 was just for two folders under `fastcgi_tmp` and `microcache` to test, I changed it back to 766, if you read my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this up with giving permission to its parent directories. `/var/cache/nginx` all had Read Only permissions, while `/var/cache/nginx/microcache/` had All permissions, it worked only after I changed `/var/` , `/var/cache/` and `/var/cache/nginx/` permission to 766. This is still weird but it works for me.

Comment: May have been SELinux messing things up, that's what just happened to me.

Comment: @nmr, thanks! you should add an aswrer mentioning selinux and how to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this error come up few times over last few days I've transitioned content from an old hardware server into AWS EC2 instance. To resolve, I've had to delete the `/var/tmp/nginx/fastcgi_temp` folder and restart nginx service. This recreates the fastcgi_temp folder and, at least for me, the problem went away after that.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this exact thing happen to me, running Amazon Linux and Nginx built from source. I fixed it by setting directory permissions as follows (you'll note I've edited the directory listing to make it more obvious which permissions you need on which directories). Note that 777 didn't work, you need 755 and these owners.

```
drwxr-xr-x 21 root root   4096 Dec 19 06:58 /var

drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Dec 18 18:43 /var/cache

drwxr-xr-x  7 nginx root 4096 Dec 18 18:45 /var/cache/nginx

drwx------  2 nginx root 4096 Dec 31 02:47 /var/cache/nginx/client_temp
drwx------ 12 nginx root 4096 Dec 27 04:09 fastcgi_temp
drwx------  2 nginx root 4096 Dec 18 18:45 proxy_temp
drwx------  2 nginx root 4096 Dec 18 18:45 scgi_temp
drwx------  2 nginx root 4096 Dec 18 18:45 uwsgi_temp
```

Answer (score 0):

I had previously deleted the `/var/cache/nginx/` folder to remove the nginx cache.  Didn't cause any trouble until I rebooted.  I simply went back in and created the folder again and my problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue, first check your nginx user and group from configuration file, my nginx user is nobody and the group is admin. then using this command to keep the group and user keep the same:

```
sudo chown -R nobody ./proxy_temp
sudo chgrp -R admin ./proxy_temp
```

replace the path `./proxy_temp` to your own path.

Answer (score -1):

This is most likely you have two or more Nginx master process and their user permission is not the same.